# Django Solr(Filter) - Выпадающий список для объектов, как реализовать? либо адаптировать

Tags: python, django, solr

Имеется такой список объектов, отображенных по значению атрибутов товаров.
[image: описание изображения]

Значения атрибутов товаров, которые связаны между собой - должны быть в форме выпадающего списка Select(option)/DropDownMenu, т.е. - к примеру вместо Size:Medium,Size:Small должно быть просто

```
Medium
Small
```

То что эти значения атрибутов относятся к Size можно указать внутри Templates(label), т.е. это не так важно, главное - каким образом их можно поместить в этот Select список (Dropdown Menu).

---

От себя хочу добавить, что я пытался изменить значения которые указывается по умолчанию, в Templates, вместо CheckBox'ксов - я пробовал указать Select Option, но результат получился неправильным

[image: описание изображения].

---

### TEMPLATES

Browse.html:

```
{% for field, data in facet_data.items %}
    {% if data.results %}
        {% include 'search/partials/facet.html' with name=data.name items=data.results %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

facet.html:

```
{% for item in items %}
<dd>
   <input class="facet_checkbox" type="checkbox" name="{{ item.name }}" />
   <input class="facet_url" type="hidden" name="url_for_{{ item.name }}" value="{{ item.select_url }}" />
   <a href="{{ item.select_url }}">{{ item.name }}</a>
    {% if item.show_count %}
        ({{ item.count }})
    {% endif %}
</dd>
```

---

`Product Class` - это класс всех продуктов (товаров), используемый для индексирования, фильтром.
Далее идет просто уточнение тех значений, которые нужно отобразить (в моем случае это значения атрибутов)

### Search_Indexes.py

```
class ProductIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    product_class = indexes.MultiValueField(null=True, faceted=True)

def prepare_product_class(self, obj):
    attributes = obj.attribute_values.all()
    if len(attributes) > 0:
        return [product_class for product_class in attributes]
```

Comment: Немного доработал ! Вместо `attributes = obj.attributes.all()` Теперь `obj.attribute_values.all()`

Comment: Т.е вместо двух чекбоксов Size: Small, Size: Medium должен быть комбобокс Size(Small|Medium) ?

Comment: @Чад да, оно выглядит так просто, т.к все закручено вокруг HayStack, там попросту нету такой формы.

Comment: @LightFusion А саму модель модно увидеть?

Comment: @Чад вот http://pastebin.com/jj17yhq9 , на сколько я понял сама модель берется не из indexes.MultiValueField, а из return Product_class.attribute_values, и там есть product = models.ForeignKey, который возвращает продукт. Весь "прикол" в том что эти самые models.Foreignkey в template - перебираются простым `{% for item in items %}`, а для полей(выбора models.ChoiceField) такое обращение не подойдет(именно в template), а вот как по другому ?

Comment: @Чад http://i.imgur.com/8P0PuUH.png?1 наконец то :D =DDD

Comment: @LighFusion, если бы вы оформили свой ответ (если он у вас есть), то получили бы немножко баллов репутации ;)

Comment: @DmitriySimushev - помоему за авто ответ баллы не начисляются ? Я могу в принципе дать кому то ответ - и он опубликует получит баллы ), а вообще ответ у меня есть но не в полной форме, точнее сказать - мой метод работает( но не для UTF8- Русских букв, в заголовке запроса и в фильтре) я сейчас дорабатываю.

Comment: @LighFusion, ответ в любой случае лучше опубликовать. Раз вы нашли его сами, вы и публикуйте ;) Возможно он поможет кому-то еще с той же проблемой.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev Извиняюсь что поднимаю старую тему, но хотелось бы узнать - нашел ли кто то решение по лучше ? ибо прошло полгода , я теперь могу оценить - какой гомно-код я намутил, чтобы решить эту проблему. И как бы я в процессе переделки всего кода, и мог бы опубликовать более лаконичное решение, но прежде хотел бы узнать - не появилось ли чего то подобного ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Раз не кто не догадался как это реализовать - придется самому объяснять.
Значения которые формируются в HayStack и перерабатываются в template - не приспособлены к выпадающему списку как таковому, по этому эти значения нужно перенаправить в форму, а в форме уже описать логику, для этого надо:
1.Создать специальный {{tag}} который будет получать значения от словаря, и добавить его в Template, выглядеть это будет так -

```
{% load choice_tags %}
```

В самом тэге нужно указать форму.

```
@register.assignment_tag()
def choice_form(request,field):
    form_class = addToChoiceForm
```

И еще 1 очень важный момент, если речь идет о Django(oscar), не знаю как у кого где описано, но в Oscar есть специальный ui.js, в которым описаны функции которые передают значения из поля, когда пользователь нажал на форму выбора,  выглядит это так:

```
o.search.initFilterWidget();
initFilterWidget: function() {
        // Auto-submit (hidden) search form when selecting a new sort-by option
        $('#id_selected_facets').on('change', function() {
            $(this).closest('form').submit();
        });
    }
```

`selected_facets`, это названия поля в вашей форме, далее в коде ее можно встретить.

Далее в Template следует передать значения от словаря.

```
{% for field, data in facet_data.items %}
{% choice_form data field as choice_form %}
```

После чего следует указать форму Get, и поместить туда поле с формой, для передачи результата в адресную строку.

```
<form method="get" class="form-horizontal">
{% include "partials/form_fields.html" with form=choice_form %}
</form>
```

Далее следует итрировать объекты полученные из словаря в choice_tags, и добавить их в массив(ну либо в словарь или вообще сразу передавать в форму).
Делается это как угодно я лично сделал так.

```
    for dataResult in request['results']:
    items.append(dataResult)
```

Ну и передаем items,field в форму AddToChoiceForm

```
    form = form_class(items,field)
```

Далее следует создать класс AddToChoiceForm Это стандартный класс не буду полностью описывать, обозначу лишь ключевые части которые нужно для формирования списка.

В начале Создаем массив `Choices=[]` , в который мы будем передавать значения из словаря. Далее итрируем объекты. Обращаемся к интересующимся нас объектам по ключу, в моем примере это имя и путь url.

```
for item  in items:
select_url = item.get('select_url')
Class_name = item.get('name')
```

И добавляем наши объекты в массив.
Тут 1 очень важный момент, чтобы избежать проблем с повторным кодированием в URL, Необходимо перекодировать все символы в простой вид для этого я использовал - родную библиотеку django purl

```
choices.append((unicode_unquote(select_url), Class_name))
```

Ну и добавляем наш массив в форму ChoiceField - выпадающий список.

```
       self.fields['selected_facets'] = forms.ChoiceField(
        choices=choices,widget=forms.Select(), label=_("Variant"))
```

И на этом все, я не учел тут проблем с уникодом(возникающих в строке заголовка), поскольку еще сам их решаю, да и вообще сам метод не совсем красивый, и возможно в самой форме потребуется чистка, поскольку если пользователь выбирает что-то другое то что было в форме остается, и в результате пользователь получает не совсем то что хотел, но пока у меня не было времени все доделать.

Если у кого то может есть вариант по лучше буду рад услышать ! а так , решил к сожалению сам !